# Not getting message in spring internal exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Using Spring Boot with JWT and sprin security..when any exception thrown from servlet filter like unauthorized,forbidden. No getting message in response. when printing stack trace its showing but not getting in final response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-26T09:09:21.684+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/users/profile"
}

@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String header = request.getHeader(JwtConstant.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(header) && header.startsWith(JwtConstant.BEARER)) {

            String authToken = header.replace(JwtConstant.BEARER, "");
            Claims claims = jwtTokenUtil.getJwtClaims(authToken);

            String username = claims.getSubject();

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                    "", getAuthoritiesFromString(claims));

            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            logger.info("authenticated user " + username + ", setting security context");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

public Claims getJwtClaims(String token) {

        Claims claims = null;

        try {
            claims = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getPublicKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            throw new CustomException(env.getProperty(ExceptionMessage.TOKEN_EXPIRED),e, ErrorCode.TOKEN_EXPIRE);
        } catch (SignatureException | MalformedJwtException e) {
            throw new CustomException(env.getProperty(ExceptionMessage.TOKEN_INVALID),e, ErrorCode.TOKEN_INVALID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomException(env.getProperty(ExceptionMessage.TOKEN_PARSING),e, ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return claims;
    }
```

i am using jwt authentication. when request contains token. then first i am getting claims from token. but if token is expired,invalid then i want to throw custom exception..but i am not able to get custom exception code and message

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Also to me it looks like it is 500 InternalServer error, not Unauthorized/Forbidden HttpStatuses.... 401/403

Comment: edited the code. i am using jwt authentication. when request contains token. then first i am getting claims from token. but if token is expired,invalid then i want to throw custom exception..but i am not able to get custom exception code and message

Comment: Which version of SpringBoot are you using?

Comment: @Eulodos 2.3.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the changes made in SpringBoot since 2.3 Release. See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content) section. Error messages are no longer included in responses by default. Add this line to your application.properties:

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

Comment: Thanks its working. can i send my custom code in it? it is possible? currently i am getting 500 code

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Actually there are quite a few ways to go about this. I think this blog from spring guys covers the most popular options, see it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: You'll probably need to configure a ControllerAdvice and create some custom ErrorResponse class, which will contain all of your required information, like this custom code, as fields.

Comment: i have already created ControllAdvise..but when exception is throwing from this servlet filter its not able to cach in controller advise..check through debugging

Comment: And you are sure, that method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` is catching Exception class that you throw? Like `@ExceptionHandler({CustomException.class})`

Comment: Yes I'm sure...When throwing custom exception from any business layer it goes to exception handler. but when it is throwing from servlet filter its not going to exception handler. Tried different solutions but not working for me

Comment: Depends on what type of exception is thrown from servlet filter I guess, did you implement a custom handler method for that as well?

Comment: @Eulodos please, may you help me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880217/spring-security-exception-handling-it-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment128735025_72880217 thanks to you I was able to add the message but I still get 500 as code and I m using ControllerAdvice with ExceptionHandler